# dropdown in html with tool tip jquery & html

Tags: jquery, html

I have dorpdown in HTML, but content of it cuts in IE as there is not enough space to make it width enough wide.

So what i want is when in click on drop down and its option collapse, one tool tip (div) should appear beside dropdown which shows full content of option on which mouse cursor is, or if I am using keyboard then on change of it div content should change. and on lost focus of drop down div should disappear.

here is some code but it require modification...

```
$("select").change(function () {

        $('selectDiv').html($("select option:selected").text());
    });
```

Problem with code is, it not show div on top when click drop down. and content not change as option change on mouse or on keyboard

Comment: what is the rpoblem with this for u.Is there any error

Comment: What's the current problem? What does your HTML & CSS look like (putting it up on jsfiddle.net might help)? I think `'selectDiv'` is probably a bad selector, but there are probably other problems that need dealing with!

Answer (score 0):

Do you something like this?

```
$("select").on('focus', function () {
    $('selectDiv').html($("select option:selected").text());
    $('selectDiv').animate({opacity:1});
});

$("select").on('blur', function () {
    $('selectDiv').html('');
    $('selectDiv').animate({opacity:0});
});
```